# Unknown database and No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a xml file which I use to get DB infomation and about database through a Java class(DB_Conn).In DB_Conn I have a getconnection() which reads the xml file and starts a conncetion like below

```
my_conn_obj = DriverManager.getConnection(my_Path.item(0).getNodeValue() + my_DBname.item(0).getNodeValue(), my_User.item(0).getNodeValue(), my_Pass.item(0).getNodeValue());
```

.In that method I return a connection object(my_conn_obj) .I have defined it has null at the start of the class 
Then In a separate Java class I use

DB_Conn db= New DB_Conn();

And whenever I need/open a connection I use

```
Connection conn;
conn=db.getconnection();
```

I have closed all the connection and have put try catch properly.It worked normally, but when I am idle for some time and then when I refresh the page I sometimes and not always get Unknown database name "null"  and No operations allowed after connection closed exceptions.

Comment: It would seem that somewhere in the code you are trying to access the connection after it has been closed.

Comment: Connections can get closed for various reasons. You need to reopen a connection if it closes, or even better use a connection pool that handles that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably happening is that the connection is left open and is timing out, or you have closed it and need to re-connect it.

So when you use

```
Connection conn;
conn=db.getconnection();
```

Make sure that in getConnection  you do something like

```
public Connection getConnection() {
  if (classRefToConnection == null || classRefToConnection.isClosed()) {
    //RE create or connect the connection before returning
  }
}
```

Comment: So I can Have put a method in DB_Conn   
public void close_dbConnection() throws Exception {
        if (my_conn_obj != null) {
            my_conn_obj.close();
        }
    }

And close my conn using this instead of conn.close(); ?

Comment: You could do that. It seems that you are wrapping the connection and its functionality in a class of your own. If this is the case then you should deligate all calls through this class to keep a standard way of talking/using the connection. It will make the code esier to understand as everything is handled in the class you have used to wrap the Connection in